# Copying libraries to Android gradle project with a task

Tags: android, gradle

I'm looking to add a task to my Android `build.gradle` file that will copy some libraries to my `libs` directory so as to be included in my resultant `.aar` file.

This is my task:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from { configurations.compile }
    into 'libs'
}
```

I can get it to execute as a `preBuild` dependency like so:

`preBuild.dependsOn copyLibs`

However, the resultant `.aar` doesn't contains the required `.jar` files.

How can I formuate this dependency so that both the jar files are only created and copied if the user invokes a task requiring a compilation and have it be available during the compilation of the app?

Comment: did you added also dependency on _libs_ folder to your dependencies like this `compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')` ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?